# Box API 2.0 : How to upload a file to your Box (apps) folder when you use /tokens API

Tags: box-api

I'm using the /tokens API from Box v2 and am able to get both the token and an apps specific folder id after I use the /tokens API. When I use this token to list all folders in my Box account, it appears to correctly list only my apps folder. However, I'm unable to upload a file to my apps folder using the token and the folder_id that I obtained from the /tokens API.

I can get the upload to work with a regular auth_token. I can't figure out how to make upload work with the instant mode token. Has anyone else had luck with this?

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: This issue has been resolved as of 6/7/2012.

We did some further investigation and it appears that there is a bug preventing uploads in Instant Mode. We're on fixing it and will hopefully have a resolution soon.